# Why are windows going to top left of the screen?

Tags: unity, window-manager

Recently I noticed all the new windows are popping up in the top left. This is annoying because the top bar blocks the title bar of the new window. See screenshot of Tunesviewer with Firefox, Tunesviewer can't be moved without alt-drag trick.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System file windows open behind Unity launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858588/system-file-windows-open-behind-unity-launcher)

Comment: Still a problem 11 years later in Ubuntu 22.04 ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah by-default Ubuntu opens it in the top-left corner of the desktop. You can open it in the centre by doing the following:

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager from the Ubuntu Software center if the   application is not in your system. You could also install it from the terminal by typing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` into the box, press Enter to run this program. (You may receive a warning to use this advanced tool with care.)
3. Select "Windows Management" from the left panel.
4. Click "Place Windows".
5. Change Placement Mode from "Smart" to "Centered", click "Back" and "Close".

Ideally, the window manager in Ubuntu should restore the last known position of an application window, but it does not do that unless an application remembers its own window position. (See reported bugs)

Comment: That is *not* default, I had unchecked it in compizconfig. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't forget to enable "Place Windows"

Comment: Does not work now, some packages are not found. :(

Comment: @Faheem , how about you try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/858960/309223

Comment: Thanks, @geras. I used the same solution to fix the issue, 6 months ago. :P