# Program opening up in the top edge of the screen, preventing it from being dragged

Tags: unity, launcher

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I didn't really know what to Google. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and sometimes when I open up a specific application, it opens up on the top left corner of the screen. That's all good, but the portion that allows you to be able to drag a window around is stuck behind the black bar menu on top that has your wifi, battery, time stuff on it. Refer to the screenshot below:

EDIT: I need 10 rep points in order to post an image so I hope people understand my issue without needing a screenshot.

As you can see, the application is launching behind the menu bar making it unable to be moved. I have to exit the application and relaunch it a few times since its place on the screen seems to be random. Is there a way to fix this or is this completely the application's fault?

Comment: You can Alt-drag the window on any position on the window :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are windows going to top left of the screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233135/why-are-windows-going-to-top-left-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are keyboard shortcuts which allow you to minimize, maximize, and move windows in Ubuntu. If you can click on the problematic application so that is active, you can use:

<kbd>Alt+Space</kbd> then <kbd>N</kbd> to Minimize,

<kbd>Alt+Space</kbd> then  <kbd>X</kbd>  to Maximize/Unmaximize, and:

<kbd>Alt+Space</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd> to Move.

If you can only invoke a menu with this shortcut:

<kbd>Alt+Sapce</kbd>

you can use the pointer (or arrow key) to highlight then select the option you'd like.

Comment: Thank you! I'd vote up your answer, but I need 15 rep points in order to do so. For now, I have marked it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the most annoying things ever!

The Unity is a compiz plugin and you are using a compiz desktop so first, install compizconfig-settings-manager. Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm &
```

Now, scroll down the screen to the Window Management category, enable the Move Window plugin and then exit ccsm.

By default, this plugin is set to initiate a window move when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + the Left Click Button on your mouse.

So, move your mouse over anywhere in the window, hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and press the left click mouse button to click and drag the offending window down from behind the panel.

Also, I seem to remember having a plugin enabled or disabled that would cause the behavior you are experiencing but can't remember what it was. Hopefully, once you close the window in a different area, it will not want to open in that awful place again.