# System file windows open behind Unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1 at the moment, and system windows like the Files window, Terminal or System Software open behind the Unity launcher, which means they are partially hidden behind it. I can move them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, but I'd like a more permanent solution to this problem.

Comment: Do they do this on _launching_  them or when you move them towards unity launcher ?

Comment: Yes, it happens when I launch them.

Answer (score 10):

Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and enable "**Place Windows**" under "*Window Management*". This should solve the problem.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you may consider ["accepting" the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. It's completely fine to accept your own answer :-)

Comment: This solution worked for me. Afterwards, is it safe to uninstall this CompizConfig Settings Manager? @pomsky , maybe you know?

Comment: @geras I'm not completely sure, perhaps it's better to keep it if it's not causing any problem?

Comment: @pomsky I have just uninstalled it and everything seems fine.

Comment: YES this solved the same problem I was having after installing Ubuntu18.04.4 and ubuntu-unity-desktop. Thankyou

Comment: This doesn't work for me on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

A permanent solution that I personally use is to set the Unity Launcher to autohide. If you go into Settings ---> Appearance and then go into the "Behavior" tab, you can select autohide. I find the top left corner option to be optimal for unhiding the Unity Launcher. This way, the Unity Launcher will only be present when you need it. You can also reveal the Unity Launcher by pressing the "Windows" key.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to autohide the launcher - so that isn't an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: I think I have the same problem as @TraceyLowndes and also the windows' title bars are hidden behind the top bar so this solution is not enough.