# How to reset the Nautilus window position?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, window-manager

Recently, on Ubuntu 16.04 the default window position of Nautilus windows is in the top left corner of the screen. The window sits behind the top menu bar and the left side Unity launcher as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Nautilus]

With a bit of precise mouse pointer positioning I am able to drag the window somewhere to the screen.

Is there a way to either **reset the default window position** or let Nautilus **remember the last window position** to fix the default behavior?

Comment: It seems that [enabling "Place windows" via Compiz Settings Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/858960/18533) resolves the issue somewhat. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem recently in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

At first try move it with <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd> and mouse/touchpad:

1. press <kbd>Alt+F7</kbd> when Nautilus window is focused
2. move it with mouse or touchpad to position

If it does not help try to reset its position with `dconf`:

```
nautilus -q
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/nautilus/window-state
nautilus &
```

Comment: Thank you but both did not work for me.