# Not full-sized windows go too far to top left of the screen and their title bar is blocked by the top bar

Tags: 16.04, unity, window-manager

It started happening recently and it is like in this question: [Why are windows going to top left of the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/233135/309223) but the solution given there doesn't work any more according to a comment under it and also, I still would like windows to open in the top left of the screen just not so much that the title bar is blocked.

It seems like this came with an update because I haven't been making any changes to my computer recently.

It doesn't happen on the guest account.

Also, just before this started happening I rebooted my computer and when I logged in only the Desktop was shown--no top bar or side bar so I had to reboot it again.

Should I report it as a bug somewhere?

I've attached a picture as an example.

[image: too-far-to-top-left]

Comment: The solution with setting the Unity Launcher to auto-hide doesn't work. I might try the one with CompizConfig Settings Manager but is it safe? If it is enough to wait for an update to fix my issue, I would prefer that.

Comment: To sum up, this solution worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/858960/309223 , now I just don't know if it is safe to uninstall this CompizConfig Settings Manager afterwards.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled it and everything seems fine.