# all windows open upper left corner

Tags: gnome-terminal, default

Since a recent update (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) all new windows are created in the upper left corner (partially covered by the menu bar and icons). How can this have happened? Can this be repaired manually? (I filed it as a bug but in between ...)

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key on the keyboard, then left-click-hold-drag the mouse pointer in an open space of the window that's hidden under the top panel. Drag the window to the desired position.

Another solution would be to install `Compiz Config Manager`, and configure the `Place Windows` pane to put the windows where you'd like them permanently.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

More details here: [Why are windows going to top left of the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233135/why-are-windows-going-to-top-left-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `gnome-shell` version `3.14` or higher you can use `dconf` option for this. open `dconf` and go to `org / gnome / mutter / center-new-windows` option and set `true`. after that all new windows open in center of screen

Comment: More details here: https://superuser.com/questions/224562/application-windows-always-open-on-the-top-left-corner-of-the-screen-on-ubuntu